# Probability of rectangles area being less than 0.5 w/ total length of sides = 2

Tags: probability, random-variables, stochastic-analysis, uniform-distribution

Question: A random point splits the interval [0,2] in two parts. Those two parts make up a rectagle. Calculate the probability of that rectangle having an area less than 0.5.

So, this is as far as I've gotten; I've set 
$X := length of one side$.

Then $Y := length of other side$. Both of the variables are uniformally distributed but Y is dependent on X. But if I set $Y = (2-X)$, then I only have to figure out the probability of $P(XY<0.5) = P(X(2-X)<0.5)$.

Here is where I can't go any further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you solve $X(2-X)<0.5$ for $X$ you get $X>1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $X<1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

The cdf of $X$ is

$F(x)=\begin{cases}0, \ \ x<0 \\ \frac{x}{2}, \ \  \ 0\leq x\leq 2 \\  1, \ \ x>0\end{cases}$

It is $F(X>x)=1-F(X<x)$

Therefore you have to calculate $F(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+(1-F(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))$

**Remark**

The distibution of $X$ is symmetric around the mean 1.

Thus $F(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+(1-F(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))=2\cdot F(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and the result reduces to the expression $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 29.29\%$

Comment: Thanks alot for a great answer. Just how did you get the cdf? Is the pdf then 1/2?

Comment: More or less. It is $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a}, a \leq x \leq b \\ 0, \ \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$ In your case with $b=2$ and $a=0$. This is wlll known from the uniform distribution. I started from here and then I integrated it to get the cdf (see my answer).
$\int_0^x \frac{1}{2} \, dt=\frac{x}{2}$. This is only valid for $0\leq x\leq 2$

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks again!

Comment: You´re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $X\sim U(0,2)$, that is the cut point is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $2$. Then if $X=x$ the area $A=a=x(2-x)$ and this is greater than a half between the roots of $x(2-x)=1/2$ which are $1\pm\sqrt{1/2}$.

The pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)=1/2$ for $x\in (0,2)$ and zero otherwise. So the probability that$A\ge 1/2$ is:

$$
P(\mbox{A} \ge 1/2)=\int_{x=1-\sqrt{1/2}}^{1+\sqrt{1/2}}\frac{1}{2}\;dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.707
$$
So the probability that the area is less than $1/2$ is 
$$
P(\mbox{A}< 1/2)=1-P(\mbox{A}\ge 1/2)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.293
$$

Comment: @SamuelLarsson: Uniform distribution over (0,2) means that the pdf is constant on this interval and its integral over the interval is 1. So if the value of the constant pdf on the interval is p then 2p=1 so p=1/2